# Fatal error: Call to undefined function json_encode

Tags: server

I migrated to new server and I am now getting this error:

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined function json_encode() in /home/weddings/public_html/includes/common.inc on line 5105
```

P.S php5-json installation does not solve problem.

Comment: What are you doing when you get the error?

Comment: Also, what version of Ubuntu are you running?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot and should not mark this as a duplicate, because it was asked on another stackexchange site, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239405/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-json-decode) question may answer the problem that you are experiencing. Incase of future deletion of said question, here is what it says. Note that everything written after this will not be my work, but @MirroredFate's.

Short answer:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-json
```

Then of course **make sure you restart Apache**:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Or if you are using PHP-FPM:

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

## Explanation

Debian has removed the previous JSON extension as of PHP 5.5rc2 due to a license conflict.

The [JSON license](http://www.json.org/license.html) has a clause which states:

> The Software shall be used for Good, not Evil.

This causes a problem with [Free Software Foundation's definition of free software](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html) which states:

> The freedom to run the program, for any purpose (freedom 0).

FSF goes on to [specifically list the JSON license as nonfree](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#JSON).

Yes it seems a bit silly. Nevertheless Debian has removed the non-compliant JSON extension, and instead offered a [replacement extension](https://github.com/remicollet/pecl-json-c) that is functionally equivalent.

To be clear: PHP itself has NOT removed JSON, it's [still in master](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/json). This is a distro / package manager issue.

[Rasmus makes it pretty clear](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63520#1391058623):

> We have not removed json and we will never release a version of php without json support built in. Any changes in 5.5 is due to whatever distro packaging you are using which we have no control over.

## More details

http://iteration99.com/2013/php-json-licensing-and-php-5-5/

http://liorkaplan.wordpress.com/2013/06/01/bye-bye-non-free-php-json-extension/

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63520

http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2013/08/fud-cracker-php-55-never-lost-json-support